# Get device orientation ( API 31 )

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

I'm trying to get Device orientation but defaultDisplay.orinentation is deprecated, What are the alternatives for this?

Please note I do not need to use orientationEventListener for this because that will trigger only when device orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getRequestedOrientation()

Activity instance is required

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs.  It tells you what it was deprecated in favor of.  In this case, defaultDisplay was deprecated in favor of Context.getDisplay().  GetOrientation was deprecated in favor of getRotation()

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative way

```
int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    // the new mode is portrate
} else {
    // the new mode is landscape
}
```